# What is the number of connected subgraphs with $n$ vertices of a labelled connected simple graph with $n$ vertices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a connected simple labeled graph.  Let $n$, $e$, and $k$ be its number of vertices, edges, and the upper bound of the degree of a vertex, respectively.  How many connected sub-graphs containing all $n$ vertices does $G$ have?  (In other words, how many connected factors $G$ has?)  Is there an algorithm that generates all such cases?

For example:

1) the Graph 0--0--0--0--0 has only one such factor.

2) a complete graph has loads of such factors 
(see [Are there more connected or disconnected graphs on $n$ vertices?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44877/are-there-more-connected-or-disconnected-graphs-on-n-vertices) )

The case I am working on lays somewhere between the above two examples.  In my situation, $n$ is large (say 3000) but the graph is sparse in the sense that each vertex has degree at most equal to 20 or 30.  Furthermore, I have a notion of distance between points - far away points cannot share an edge.  The situation is similar to connecting the cities of a country with roads - there are loads of cities, but each city will have few roads emanating from it, and cities that are far away will not share a direct road.  All cities should connected to the transportation grid.  How many such grids are there?  In other words, I am trying to count the number of $(1,20)$-Factors.  I need to know this number to check if the brute force computation I am considering is not feasible.

Comment: Pick a connected spanning tree of your labeled graph.  It has N edges, and your graph has about 10N edges.  This alone suggests at least 500^N connected subgraphs which contain this tree. I would not attempt brute force for N greater than 22.

Comment: Would you know, by any chance, how many spanning trees are there?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem counts spanning trees.